# php sorting and grouping

Tags: php, sorting, grouping

Currenty I am working on file content sorting and grouping 
for example I have this txt file

**Input**

```
 - Test_test01.abc 
 - Test_test02.abc 
 - Test_testaroony.abc
 - Test_testBits32.abc
 - Test_testBits3202.abc 
 - Test_testBits16.abc
 - Test_testBits1602.abc
```

**Expected output**

```
Group:

 - Test_test01.abc
 - Test_test02.abc

Group:

 - Test_testaroony.abc

Group:

 - Test_testBits16.abc
 - Test_testBits1602.abc
 - Test_testBits32.abc
 - Test_testBits3202.abc
```

Here is my starting code (obviously need to improve :))

```
 <?php
    $names = array(
                   "Test_test01.abc",
                   "Test_test02.abc",
                   "Test_testaroony.abc",
                   "Test_testBits3202.abc",
                   "Test_testBits16.abc",
                   "Test_testBits1602.abc"
                   );
    sort($names);

    $nlength = count($names);
    for($x = 0; $x < $nlength; $x++) {
        echo $names[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

And Output

```
 - List item
 - Test_test01.abc
 - Test_test02.abc
 - Test_testBits16.abc
 - Test_testBits1602.abc 
 - Test_testBits32.abc
 - Test_testBits3202.abc
 - Test_testaroony.abc
```

Can I get a bit of help please :)

Comment: Firstly you must decide on which rule you want to group those items. The single rule I can think off would be the first char after `Test_test`

Comment: Also, I recommend you to use `natsort` instead of `sort`

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented you must decide a rule to group the items by. Also it would be recommended to use `natsort` instead of `sort`:

```
$names = array("Test_test01.abc", "Test_test02.abc", "Test_testaroony.abc",
 "Test_testBits32.abc", "Test_testBits3202.abc", "Test_testBits16.abc", "Test_testBits1602.abc");
natsort($names);

$result = array_reduce($names, function ($carry, $item) {
    if (!isset($carry[$item[9]])) {
        $carry[$item[9]] = [$item];
    } else {
        $carry[$item[9]][] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

$result = array_values($result);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result would be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Test_test01.abc"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "Test_test02.abc"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "Test_testBits16.abc"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "Test_testBits32.abc"
    [2]=>
    string(21) "Test_testBits1602.abc"
    [3]=>
    string(21) "Test_testBits3202.abc"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "Test_testaroony.abc"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. rule would be to sort by two_digi, one_digit or no_digit pattern

Comment: Hi why du you use ($carry[$item[9]])) , why 9?